# How to avoid updating child tables when using save Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a parent table called USER and a child table called USERDATA linked with OneToMany. When I go to use the save method, if the child record exists it is updated. I would like it not to be updated but not added. What am I doing wrong?

My classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@IdClass(UserPK.class)
public class User implements Serializable{
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="USERID")
    private String userId;
    @Id
    @Column(name="USERNUMBER")
    private String userNumber;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserData> userDatas;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<OtherData> otherDatas;
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

UserData:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERDATA")
public class UserData implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String City;
    private String University;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName = "USERID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "USERNUMBER", referencedColumnName = "USERNUMBER")
    })
    private User user;
    //getter and setter
```

OtherData:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OTHERDATA")
public class OtherData implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String hobby;
    private String religion;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName = "USERID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "USERNUMBER", referencedColumnName = "USERNUMBER")
    })
    private User user;
    //getter and setter
```

And my save:

```
session.save(obj); //obj is and User object
```

when I do the first insert everything is ok, when I do it again by changing the data of the primary key of user but not quelly of the primary key of userData or otherData, the data is updated. I don't want them updated.

Comment: You have cascade = CascadeType.ALL set This will cascade all operations to the children

Comment: with the save I want to insert and not update, I expect that if there is a child with that key, it will not be inserted. the cascade = CascadeType.ALL I need it when I delete

Comment: Yes that's exaclty how it works. Can you show the update statement that is produced?

Comment: My console autput:
 Hibernate: insert into USER (name, surname, USERID, USERNUMBER) values (?,?,?,?);
 Hibernate: update USERDATA set city=?, university=? where id=?
 Hibernate: update OTHERDATA set hobby=?, religion=? where id=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not reuse the same Java object in this case. Also, changing the primary key should produce a big fat warning when flushing that object Hibernate.

If you want a new row to be inserted, you have to create a new object with `new User()`. Another option is to let Hibernate forget about the old object by using `session.detach(user)`. The problem is, that Hibernate knows the object already and due to that, tries to update the existing row when you call `save` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the column like so:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<UserData> userDatas;
```

I haven't tested it but it should block inserts and updates via the entity. Of course you will need separate queries to insert update UserData somehow.

BTW I suggest not to use FetchType.EAGER, but always use FetchType.LAZY. If you need the child data to be fetched, just adapt the query you are using to do a FETCH JOIN, see [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/fetch-join.html) for an example:

```
SELECT FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.userData d
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Fesilox Please write this example

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName = "USERID", nullable = false, 
insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

Comment: When using many to one, do not use an intermediate table, that is, let there be a single child, a single parent table, then it will work